# How to use my personal machine as a node in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, cluster-computing, sharding

I need an additional machine to use it as a node in MongoDB cluster and I am wondering if there is a way to turn my personal machine (a remote machine outside of the cluster network) as a node at least for now.

Comment: This seems more of a networking problem than a mongo problem.